# Dealing with bash breaking commands of a certain length

Tags: command-line, bash

Consider you want to run this command in `bash`:

```
echo -n "Command of a specific length will break at the second run attempt."
```

Here's the output for a 24x80 TTY:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo -n "Command of a specific length will break at the second 
run attempt."
Command of a specific lenght will break at the second run attempt.ubuntu@ubuntu:
~$
```

Consider you want to run the same command again.

As soon as you hit <kbd>↑</kbd>:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo -n "Command of a specific lenght will break at the second
run attempt."
Command of a specific lenght will break at the second run attempt.ubuntu@ubuntu:
run attempt."ommand of a specific lenght will break at the second r
```

This happens with commands of a certain size which don't print a newline at the end.

This is extremely annoying. So far I haven't found any solution to this, and I think everyone who's experiencing this issue would be **really** grateful to someone who has a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `bash` too. The trick is to use a custom `PROMPT_COMMAND` that queries the terminal for the position of the cursor (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343250/how-can-i-get-position-of-cursor-in-terminal) ).

This solution can probably be extended to other shells, but I'm only familiar with `bash`. (See @muru 's answer for a `zsh` solution). And perhaps there is already an option in `bash` to do this automatically.

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
function new.line.if.not.on.left {
    local foo
    local garbage
    local column
    echo -n -e "\033[6n"     # as the terminal for the position
    read -s -d \[ garbage    # ignore the first part of the response
    read -s -d R foo         # store the position in foo
    column="$(echo "$foo" | cut -d';' -f2)"    # skip over the row number
    test "$column" "!=" 1 && { tput smso; echo "%"; tput rmso; }
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="new.line.if.not.on.left; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

The last line prepends a call to `new.line.if.not.on.left` to your `PROMPT_COMMAND` (as you may already have a `PROMPT_COMMAND` defined).

The bash function `new.line.if.not.on.left` works as follows:

- `echo -n -e "\033[6n"` is a piece of magic that asks the terminal about the row and column of the cursor's current position. The terminal "responds" by sending fake keyboard input with the answer.
- `read -s -d \[ garbage`. The first part of the response is some gibberish, some sort of escape code. Ignore it by storing it in `garbage`.
- `read -s -d R foo` . Store the fake keyboard response in bash variable `foo`. The `-s` is needed to stop `read` from echoing the input to the screen again. And `-d R` is the delimiter - the fake input is terminated by an `R`, not by a newline as you might expect.
- `column="$(echo "$foo" | cut -d';' -f2)"` extracts the column number from the response (i.e. skipping over the row number) and stores the result in `column`
- `test "$column" "!=" 1 && { tput smso; echo "%"; tput rmso; }` If the current column number is not 1, then print the percent sign (and a newline). The `tput` commands turn on "stand out mode" - which should make the `%` stand out more - perhaps bold or perhaps by reversing the background and foreground colours.

Comment: Works flawless. I just switched to `zsh` as per muru's suggestion, and I think I'll stick to it but indeed I'm leaving this into my `~/.bashrc` for when I have to use `bash`. Thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a smarter shell, like `zsh`:

[image]

Note how it added a `%` to indicate the lack of a newline and printed the prompt on a different line.

Comment: So this is related to the shell and not to `gnome-terminal`. Nice, I'm considering this. Hopefully it won't diverge too much from `bash`.

Comment: @kos mostly in pleasant ways.

Comment: @kos it diverges quite a bit but as far as I can tell (haven't taken the plunge and switched to it yet) it is just better in pretty much any way you can imagine. If that doesn't convince you, let me just say that people like muru, [Stéphane](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) and [Gilles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) all use `zsh`.

Comment: @kos and, well, if you're debugging, it's always useful to have [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Ok I just did that, I think I'll make it work, It's not that I'm using `bash` from a decade. Thanks for the fix, I'm leaving this open for a while to incourage people posting a `bash` fix if any.

Answer (score 3):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. That will redraw your terminal and make everything appear as it should:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's nicer than Ctrl + C (and thanks for the cool GIF), however I was hoping for a definitive fix. Sometimes when you make small changes this is hardly visible and will break your command without you even noticing or understanding why. This also gets exponentially more annoying when you're trying to fix a non-working command: even if you theoretically made it at the first attempt you'd still end up debugging stuff completely unrelated because you didn't notice a single missing character.