# Typing the command too long eats up the prompt when using the promptline theme

Tags: command-line, bash, themes, gnome-terminal

I am using the [edkolev/promptline.vim](https://github.com/edkolev/promptline.vim) theme(just installed it) for customizing the bash prompt. The biggest problem is that whenever I type long comments it replaces the prompt instead of continuing to the newline. **Earlier when I used to have my prompt set via `PS1` I could easily solve out the problem. But here I don't know which files to look and what to do** .I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see in the second line When I type `sudo vim slices.vim` it overwrites it. So, How can I solve it?

**UPDATE 1.0 ->** I could not found a solution to this problem , I assume there is a bug in the plugin. Instead of this I installed [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) . It solved all my problems. Installing it through vundle eased my way.

**UPDATE 2.0 (not a bug actually)->** The demon arrives again.The problem has started again even with the powerline.This time I noticed that this problem is connected with the *arrow-shaped triangular prompt * only. So , this is not a bug, basically a glitch somewhere I am missing.

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640819/dealing-with-bash-breaking-commands-of-a-certain-length) your problem?

Comment: @kos This is also a problem ,i.e pressing the `UP` arrow key results in the problem in your link , also my problem which is the commands replaces itself or the prompt. I don't the think that I would have the same solution because I am not using `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in bashrc because I am using a theme (promptline ) which I assume has settings somewhere else like in the `/autoload/promptline.vim/slices.vim` but I don't know how to edit it to solve my problem

Comment: Looks like a bug with that prompt. Have you contacted the author or filed a bug report?

Comment: I have stated the problem in issues but got no response up till now .

Comment: This symptom usually occurs when in bash's PS1 the control characters (escape sequences that do not advance the cursor but rather set colors etc.) are not enclosed between `\[` and `\]`. These delimiters around escape sequences are required so that bash can keep track of the columns.

Comment: @egmont I know that and I have solved this before but this time its different the prompt is controlled by a theme and its files but I don't know how.

Comment: Well, you could still examine PS1 to see if it properly contains those characters. This won't get you to a solution right away, but you'd understand if this is the reason for the buggy behavior.

Comment: I have  the same PS1  that I used to have before installing promptline ,so this can not be the reason as it is not controlled by the `bashrc` I think. Earlier with the same PS1 I didn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem .I think the shell was not using `~/.local/lib/python2.7/...../bindings/bash/powerline.sh` so I resourced it and restarted the system.

I also added the path variable for `powerline-config` file in the `~/.local/bin/poweline` directory in `.bashrc` and now, everything is working just fine.